# Can I train parts of a composite model without recompiling?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a composite model (`model_12`) that is comprised of two smaller models, `model_1` and `model_2`. e.g.:

```
model12 = keras.Model(inp, model_2(model_1(inp))
```

My training procedure is such that I want to train `model_2` by itself, then train `model_1` from within the composite model with `model_2` fixed, like this:

```
while True:
   ...
   model_2.trainable = True
   model_2.compile(...)
   model_2.fit(...)
   model_2.trainable = False
   model_12.compile(...)
   model_12.fit(...)
```

This is very inefficient due to the constant recompiling. Is there a more efficient way?  In particular if I simply compiled these models once with the trainable flags as I need them, will they stick that way, with `model2` weights updating when `model2.fit` is called, but not when `model_12.fit` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you compile the models initially you can change its training attribute without the need to recompile the model.